# What is lack of extension on a wallet?

Tags: wallet

I received this message below, is this an attempt to scam ?

Dear customer,

Your bitcoin transaction is awaiting for clearance on end-wallet.
The transaction could not be completed due to the lack of extension on the wallet.
For such transactions you need to pass through an additional check.
The transactionwill be confirmed and released automatically once the wallet is verified.
Note that the current clearance level is BTC 8.36601711
Current balance which is awaiting clearance BTC 9.78821802
Your wallet requires additional clearance BTC 1.42220091

TxID:
cd6654ddddfce0c14cdd2fb3ea201c108041346c0032a6a10513dc89893fd569

Regards
Support team

Coin-to

Answer (score 0):

That message appears to be nonsense, so I am thinking it's a scam.

Comment: It is very obviously a scam. See the question I linked to.